# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'calculate' before initialization at hesapmakinesi3.html:10

Tags: javascript

I take 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'calculate' before initialization     at hesapmakinesi3.html:10'
I can't see where error
I don't know any do this

```
  $: strValue =prompt("Please! enter the value ");
  $: abc=calculate(strValue);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = abc;
  const calculate = s => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing much, it looks like you're trying to call a method `calculate` before it's actually initialized.

You want to first initialize it:

```
const calculate = s => {};
```

and then use it after it's being declared.

Comment: thank you my dude I am new this topic this simple error :)

Answer (score 0):

You're currently trying to use `calculate` before you've defined it.  According to the rules on [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting):

> Variables declared with `let` and `const` are also hoisted, but unlike for `var` the variables are not initialized with a default value of `undefined`. Until the line in which they are initialized is executed, any code that accesses these variables will throw an exception.

So you are seeing that exception.

First *define* `calculate`.  *Then* you can use `calculate`:

```
const strValue = prompt("Please! enter the value ");
const calculate = s => {
  //.. whatever your function definition is
};
const abc = calculate(strValue);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = abc;
```

(As an aside, I've also added `const` declarations for your other variables.  If they are already declared elsewhere, don't re-declare them here of course.  But for completeness of this example I'm simply demonstrating that variables should have declarations so as to not pollute the `window` object with properties that should have been declared variables.)